# Adding structured data to an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create sample data to test a form Grid. And am using the following function to try and create the data to send to my grid.

```
// populateFields: Populates data n times a record of data for the SSM form.
// @params: n, fips, products
// @returns: fields
populateFields(n, fips, products) {
    var data = [];
    var fields = this.getFields();


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var x = {fields[0]: false, 
        fields[1]: fips[getRandomInt(0, fips.length())], 
        fields[2]: products[getRandomInt(0, products.length())], 
        fields[3]: getRandomInt(0, 100)};
        data.push(x);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Nothing gets populated when I call it. I get an error saying `fields[0]: false` needs `[` token.

Note: This is part of a class, I don't think that matters.
I am not sure if you want to see how I call it.

Is it because of jQuery, as in what I am passing the array to.

Comment: One other minor issue: you don't declare your loop counter, `i`.

Comment: One question, though: does `getFields()` return varying results?  If so, how do you know that `fields[1]` has anything to do with "fips" or that `fields[2]` is related to "products"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a variable as a property key it has to be enclosed in brackets:

```
 {
   [fields[0]]: false
   //...
 }
```

Otherwise it would try to use `field[0]` as an identifier itself, and some characters like `[` arent allowed in identifiers (cause they are used for property access). (They are allowed in property names though, so `{ "field[0]": false }` would work syntactically, but that makes little sense).

Comment: @raxenx glad to help :)

Comment: The commentary is slightly misleading.  The new(ish) bracket syntax for Object keys allows us to do in a single step what previously took multiple steps.  (`myObj = { ... }; myObj[fieldName] = value; ...`), but it doesn't change what is an allowable property name, Symbols and any Strings.  So this is a perfectly acceptable property name: `"(ab [no I ^meant cd])!"` even though its full of spaces and special characters.  Of course that isn't a legal identifier name, but that's a slightly different question than one about object property names.

Comment: @scott yup but without the `[]` or `""` its an identifier.